# iPhone 6 plus device width seems not equal between the simulator and real device when using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

I type **alert(windows.screen.width)** in mobile safari of the iPhone 6 plus simulator and the real device, and the simulator says it is **414** but the real device says **375**,so why they are different?

Comment: Is it because one is an iPhone 6 and the other is an iPhone 6 Plus?  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754848/what-are-the-device-width-css-viewport-sizes-of-the-iphone6-and-iphone-6-plus

Comment: @DanielBank Thanks for your reply.But nope, both of them are iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: hi @happylyang have you found the answer ?:)

Comment: @iamdavidlam Sadly,no.