# My iPhone 6 gets the iPhone 5 media query

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I can't figure out what is going on here.
I have in my CSS media query specially for iphone 5:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    #some-div {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I open the web page on my Iphone 6 and for some reason this media query kicks in and that div is hidden.

When I check my device's width on test site like: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest_vpdevice.html
It shows width/height of: 320/568.

What is the problem here and how it can be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using aspect ratio instead of absolute pixels as outlined below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848217/4824030

> Another useful media feature is device-aspect-ratio.
>
> Note that the iPhone 5 does not have a 16:9 aspect ratio. It is in
>   fact 40:71.
>
> iPhone < 5: @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
>
> iPhone 5: @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}
>
> iPhone 6: @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375) {}
>
> iPhone 6 Plus: @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {}
>
> iPad: @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}

Comment: Tried it now, it doesn't work, still get's the iphone 5 media query. Actually, this iphone has the exact screen resolution of iphone 5, although it is iphone 6. Really weird. I don't know how to design my css with no way to test it on iphone 6 resolution.

Comment: Then you don't have an iPhone 6. The iPhone 6 resolution is completely different from the iPhone 5. http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Apple-iPhone-6,Apple-iPhone-5/phones/8346,7378

However, check to see if you have DisplayZoom enabled. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25757310/4824030