# Iphone 5/SE CSS media query changes getting applied on Iphone 6/7/8 resolution as well

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media-queries, css-in-js

Well, it's similar to [My iPhone 6 gets the iPhone 5 media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642326/my-iphone-6-gets-the-iphone-5-media-query) ques, but I am still unable to figure out the answer.

I have a CSS written in Iphone 5/SE media query as below :

```
'@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)' : {
    shippingPrice : {
        fontSize : '12px',
        width : '29%'
    }
}
```

The same CSS is getting applied for Iphone 6/7/8 devices as well. I am using `CSS in JS`.

Comment: try using `min-width` instead of `min-device-width` and why are there single quotes at the beginning of the query?

Comment: @Halnex I put (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) at the end and it worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion. Single quotes are required for CSS in JS syntax as this is not in CSS file.