# What are the device-width css for iphone7 plus?

Tags: css, iphone, device-width

I need to detect the devices for IOS devices  by JS,
for iphone-6 I check it by the ratio and devicePixelRatio,
I didn't find any information to check if the device is iPhone 7 plus.

I found information for the older devices,

[What are the device-width css viewport sizes of the iPhone6 and iPhone 6 Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754848/what-are-the-device-width-css-viewport-sizes-of-the-iphone6-and-iphone-6-plus/39815069#39815069)

or this

http://mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: What do you need this information for?

Comment: how to dedect in js if its iphone 6 or iphone 7?

Answer (score 6):

iPhone 7 has same device width/height as the iPhone 6: 375x667
iPhone 7 plus according the same: 414x736

Comment: how you dedect in js  if it's iphone 6 or iphone 7?

Comment: maybe pixel ratio can help you out. Try with window.devicePixelRatio

Comment: @amir it is possible with matchmedia. it works on every new browser down to IE10. as you can see on can i use here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia
more infos about matchmedia: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 2):

You can easily detect your device CSS width and height by single clicking this link: http://viewportsizes.com/mine/

For iPhone 6 its 375px X 667px 
For iPhone 6+ its 375px x 667px 
For iPhone 7 its 375px X 667px 
For iPhone 7+ its 414px x 736px

Comment: 6 Plus is 375⨉667 and 7 Plus is 414⨉736 according to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 7 Plus is 414 x 736 according to Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html